# How to await on a function before Build in a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I'm awaiting a GEOLOCATOR function to fetch location from the user. But during the initial build I always get an error(latitude was called on null) for a few seconds before the location is actually retrieved from the GEOLOCATOR. How do I make it so that the LOCATION is actually fetched before the page is built?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class DistancingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DistancingPage(this.uid);
  @override
  _DistancingPageState createState() => _DistancingPageState();
}

class _DistancingPageState extends State<DistancingPage> {
Position position;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPos();
  }

  Future<void> getPos() async {
    Position p = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

    setState(() {
      position = p;
    });
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Distancing Alerts'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
),
body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'YOUR CURRENT POSITION',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red[800],
                  ),
                ), //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
                Text(position.latitude.toString() +
                    '° N , ' +
                    position.longitude.toString() +
                    '° E'),
],
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot do that, you cant wait for future while building a UI, but you can update the UI once the data is available, use a FutureBuilder for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `FutureBuilder` widget where the future is your async function and builder is whatever you want to return (the scaffold in your case). Check if the future has returned anything with `snapshot.hasData` and return a progress indicator (or anything you want) if it hasn't returned anything.

```
    FutureBuilder(
      future: getPos(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
    snapshot.hasData ? 
      Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text('Distancing Alerts'),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
        ),
        body: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'YOUR CURRENT POSITION',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red[800],
                          ),
                        ), //THE ERROR OCCURS HERE
                        Text(position.latitude.toString() +
                            '° N , ' +
                            position.longitude.toString() +
                            '° E'),
        ],
                    ))) : CircularProgressIndicator();};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a temporary page with some animation from flutter_spinkit. On that page you awaiting a GEOLOCATOR function, and when it will return a value you will navigate to your main screen

Comment: Or you can fetch the location the background if the app is in foreground, there is article how to do it https://medium.com/@pierre.sabot/how-to-fetch-user-location-in-background-with-flutter-e3494021bdf5